# multiple user for Android

Tags: multi-user

I have a Le Pan Mini with Android 4.2.2. It's obviously not the greatest device but it's what I could afford and most importantly it has 4.2 which is supposed to support multiple users.

But it doesn't.

I am sure I have the 4.2.2 but users doesn't pop up in the settings menu. Any ideas on what I should do?

Answer (score 4):

In Android 4.2, only tablets support multiple user profiles, not phones. This means it's up to the manufacturer to enable multiple users when they set up Android for the device (what's called *system integration*). Since the Le Pan Mini is a tablet, they should have turned on this support. You should report this bug to the manufacturer (and let us know what they say, to help future visitors).

It's sometimes possible to change this using a customized, unofficial firmware, but that relies on having a community of knowledgeable users who can do the work necessary to create a new firmware image: this is very hard without the manufacturer's support. Since your device is not a mainstream one, it's unlikely there are enough interested people with the necessary skills.

Answer (score 0):

Get root and then install the Xposed framework:

http://mdc.gd/xposedfw

And then the MoDaCo Toolkit:

http://www.modaco.com/topic/361634-xmod-modaco-toolkit-for-xposed-framework/

Once everything is installed, and the MoDaCo module is activated inside Xposed framework (you need to go back into it once it's installed and running and do this), you can then enable multi-users in MoDaCo (as well as many, many other hacks - BE CAREFUL!).

After a reboot, go into your Android settings and there will be a "Users" section. Enjoy!

This all works perfectly on my Son's similarly cheap Ondo V701s. I have the primary account (which gets root access and other goodies), he gets a pared-down desktop with mostly games.

One thing to note; my "Onda Desktop" refused to function on the second user's account and I installed Nova, removed the default launcher. I'm guessing other Chinese tablet manufacturer's will have similarly flakey custom launchers. The Standard Android 4.4 launcher also works well (I briefly played with GoogleHome.apk v0.9.6.886092).